# strongly connected component in C

Tags: c, tarjans-algorithm

I am working on implementation of strongly connected component using Tarjan's algorithm. I am giving input as a linked list of nodes and edges. However, gcc compiler gives segmentation fault every time in the recursive function(where in the while loop I am checking for adjacent nodes of a vertex).

Any idea what's wrong in this code?

```
void strongconnect(int Vertex)
{
 struct sc_node * Ver;
 Ver = search_node(Vertex);
 Ver->sc_index = ind; //accessing the index information of node
 Ver->sc_lowlink = ind; // accessing the link information of node
 //Ver->visited = 1;
 ind++;
 int w;
 push(Vertex);

 struct sc_node * to_link, *to_link1;
 int to_lowlink,to_index;
 int flowlink;
 int min;
 int from_index;

 edge_trav = edge_head;    

 while(edge_trav != NULL)   //accessing linked list of edges
 {
   if(edge_trav->from_vertex == Vertex)
   {
     to_link = search_node(edge_trav->to_vertex);
     to_lowlink = to_link->sc_lowlink;
     to_index = to_link->sc_index;
     to_link1 = search_node(Vertex);
     flowlink = to_link1->sc_lowlink;
     from_index =  to_link1->sc_index;

     if(to_index == 0)
     {   Vertex = to_link->sc_data;
          printf("INSIDE RECURSION");
          strongconnect(Vertex);   // recursive loop
          min = minimum(flowlink,to_lowlink);
          to_link1->sc_lowlink = min;
     }
     else 
     {
       min =  minimum(flowlink, from_index);
       to_link1->sc_lowlink = min;
     }  }
  edge_trav = edge_trav->next;
  }
  Ver = search_node(Vertex);
  if(Ver->sc_lowlink == Ver->sc_index)
  {
   do
   {
    w = pop();
    printf("%d\t",w);
   }while(w != Vertex);
  }
}
```

Comment: You *do* have a valid exit condition in the recursion? To find crashes like segmentation fault you should use a debugger.

Comment: What prevents you from debugging this yourself? https://twitter.com/rkennedy/status/365678718993170433

Comment: Your general coding style is lacking, no offense. One of the first lines of code, `Ver = search_node(Vertex);` should be something like `if (NULL == (Ver = search_node)) { return ENOMEM; }`. You aren't even checking to see if your functions have succeeded. You should really refactor your code to do this before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you compile you program with gcc's `-s` and then run your program with `valgrind`. It's very useful memory leak checker. With it, you can figure out by yourself with is you program accessing an illegal memory position. As @Dogbert pointed, it looks you are dereferencing an `NULL` pointer.